# Logout function

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using a windows form application where a login form (login prompt) is used to authenticate an user and then open the application. Let us assume that I have a default admin username and password for logging in. When I click the close button of the application or choose File--> Exit, I want logout to be implemented so that the user has to again log in using his credentials when he starts the application for the next time. I want this to take place using C#

Any help on this guys?

Comment: you neither provide enough details to help (like how is the login implement? DB? Session Management ? AD ?) not do you provide any source code of waht you have tried with a description what is not working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally,if you close the application its credientials will automatically go off. The application will start from stratch the next time you start.

In the scenario where the login session is carried over, do your logout tasks on `FormClosing` Event or `FormClosed` Event; when the form is closed, the session will not carry over.

Comment: @Harish Kumar: Have you have used any kind of way for persisting the credentials (object persistance) ?

If you have not done anything for persistance, just blindly close your app. When the form runs for next time it will start from stratch.

Comment: i am not persisting the details Madhana. In that case, I think your words are true :)

Comment: Then its fine. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You could implement logout actions inside the OnFormClosing() event handler of the form.

Answer (score 1):

Your is user is authenticated only during the app start. If you will not implement some persistence mechanism to store the credentials or something like "cookie", then there's no need to deal with it - user will be prompted for credentials and authenticated on startup again.

Answer (score 0):

Try logout on [Form.Closing Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: is there a single line of code that would allow me t do that? Like application.logout() /??

Answer (score 0):

you can add event handler for FormClosedEventHandler and log off the user on that event.

consider SystemEvents.SessionEnded event and Form.Closing Events

Comment: is there a single line of code that would allow me to do that?

Comment: it depends on your login/logout implimentation